# Bode plot starting phase (real poles) [control theory]

Tags: control-theory

I am trying to sketch the bode phase plot for this transfer function:

$$H(s)=\frac{s-400}{(s+2)*(s+20)}$$

As far as I understand the phase diagram should start from 0 degrees as the poles are real and non zero. But as long as I plot the function on Wolfram Alpha I get a different result. As you can see the plot starts from 180 degrees.

[Phase diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YArr.png)

Could someone please explain why?

Comment: This is for the numerator phase $\angle \frac{j\omega}{400}-1$

Answer (score 2):

This is because your DC gain is negative. Formally, when you compute $H(j\omega)$ for $\omega=0$, where $j:=\sqrt{-1}$, you obtain $H(0)=-10$, which corresponds in the complex plane to the vector with the magnitude $10$ and the phase $-\pi$ (or $\pi$, up to you).

Actually, this is why for systems with a negative DC gain, it is typically recommended to premultiply them by $-1$, and then proceed with control design, otherwise, the phase margin can be rather poor.